# for loop code needs performance improvement

Tags: java

I would need your advice to improve the following code because it takes so much time to execute method1 and method2.  When I execute RemoveFullyContains I am calling method1 and method2. I have placed a time counter around both method and noticed that it takes so much time to execute both methods. May be someone can give me a guidance to improve it.

```
public static List<VG> RemoveFullyContains(List<VG> lTree) {
        for (int x = lTree.size()-1; x >= 0; x--) {
            VG vg1 = lTree.get(x);
            for (int y = lTree.size()-1; y >= 0; y--) {
                if (y != x) {
                    VG vg2 = lTree.get(y);
                    if (method1(vg2.getAndVar(), vg1.getAndVar())) {
                        if (method2(vg1.getNotVar(), vg2.getNotVar())) {
                            lTree.remove(x);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        return lTree;
    }

    private boolean method1(List<String> searchList, List<String> mainList) {
        if (searchList == null || searchList.size() == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if (mainList == null || mainList.size() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if (searchList.size() > mainList.size()) {
            return false;
        }
        for (String item : searchList) {
            if (!mainList.contains(item)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean method2(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
        if ((list1 == null || list1.size() == 0) && (list2 == null || list2.size() == 0)) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((list1 == null || list1.size() == 0) || (list2 == null || list2.size() == 0)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (list1.size() != list2.size()) {
            return false;
        }
        for (String item : list1) {
            if (!list2.contains(item)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } 

VG is a class that has the following methods: hashcode, equal and clone
public class VG {
    private List<String> andVar = new ArrayList();
    private List<String> notVar = new ArrayList();
    private List<VG> orVar = new ArrayList();
    private VG parent;
....
}
```

Comment: Can someone help me please? for the above for loops, Tried to replace it with if (!mainList.contains(searcList)) but the result is the same when I try to display the counter time

Answer (score 0):

if the `List`s will never be null you could remove the null checks.  Of course most of the time will be spent iterating the `List`s.

Since the same `List`s are being re-used it would be faster to use a `Set` to give constant time lookup.  There's a penalty for building the `Set`but re-using the same `Set` for the next iteration would be faster.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Method1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Method1 methods = new Method1();

        List<VG> vgs = new ArrayList<VG>(1000);
        System.out.print("building VGs...");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            vgs.add(methods.buildVg(i));
        }
        System.out.println("complete.");

        System.out.print("testing method1 using List...");
        long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < vgs.size() - 2; i++) {
            VG currentVG = vgs.get(i);
            VG nextVG = vgs.get(i + 1);
            methods.method1(currentVG.getAndVar(), currentVG.getAndVar());
            methods.method1(currentVG.getAndVar(), nextVG.getAndVar());
            methods.method1(nextVG.getAndVar(), currentVG.getAndVar());
            methods.method1(nextVG.getAndVar(), nextVG.getAndVar());
        }
        System.out.println("completed in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - current) + " ms");

        System.out.print("testing method1 using Set...");
        current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < vgs.size() - 2; i++) {
            VG currentVG = vgs.get(i);
            VG nextVG = vgs.get(i + 1);
            methods.method1(currentVG.getAndVarAsSet(), currentVG.getAndVarAsSet());
            methods.method1(currentVG.getAndVarAsSet(), nextVG.getAndVarAsSet());
            methods.method1(nextVG.getAndVarAsSet(), currentVG.getAndVarAsSet());
            methods.method1(nextVG.getAndVarAsSet(), nextVG.getAndVarAsSet());
        }
        System.out.println("completed in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - current) + " ms.");
    }

    private VG buildVg(int i) {
        VG vg = new VG();

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>(6000);
        for (int j = 0; j < 6000; j++) {
            String s = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            strings.add(i + s + j);
        }

        vg.setAndVar(strings);
        return vg;
    }

    private boolean method1(Collection<String> searchList, Collection<String> mainList) {
        if (searchList.size() == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if (mainList.size() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if (searchList.size() > mainList.size()) {
            return false;
        }

        for (String item : searchList) {
            if (!mainList.contains(item)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private class VG {
        private List<String> andVar = new ArrayList<String>();
        private Set<String> andVarSet;

        public List<String> getAndVar() {
            return andVar;
        }

        public void setAndVar(List<String> andVar) {
            this.andVar = andVar;
        }

        public Set<String> getAndVarAsSet() {
            if (andVarSet != null) {
                return andVarSet;
            }

            andVarSet = new HashSet<String>(andVar.size());
            andVarSet.addAll(andVar);
            return andVarSet;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
building VGs...complete.
testing method1 using List...completed in 140966 ms
testing method1 using Set...completed in 1755 ms.
```

If you're using java 8 then streams might be able to make it even faster.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew S. I notice that using a Set is very interesting but the problem is that my list contains duplicate elements that is why I am using a list

Comment: I am using java 8